# What will passing a Dictionary into Controller.Json return?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, json

Let's say I have a `Dictionary<string,object>` like so:

```
var foo = new Dictionary<string, object>();
foo["bar"] = new
{
    Quux = "bacon",
    Quinge = 42
};
foo["baz"] = DateTime.Now;
```

I expect it the result to the user would be akin to:

```
{"bar":{"Quux":"bacon","Quinge":42},"baz":"2009-12-02 17:23:00"}
```

However, it could just as easily be:

```
[{"Key":"bar","Value":{"Quux":"bacon","Quinge":42}},
{"Key":"baz","Value":"2009-12-02 17:23:00"}]
```

Which will it be, and if it's the latter, what do I need to do to ensure that I get the former?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's like the first one, although the property names don't have quotes. Also dates dont get serialized like that, instead you get a call to the Date() javascript function.

Answer (score 2):

It returns:

```
{"bar":{"Quux":"bacon","Quinge":42},"baz":"\/Date(1259795535958)\/"}
```

If you need to do any JSON stuff in .NET I would recommend having a gander at the [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) library.

HTHs,
Charles

Comment: Quite happy with the JSON features I get as part of ASP.NET MVC, tyvm.

Comment: Sure. You are aware that I got that result from the built in ASP.NET MVC stuff? Was simple to spike. I was merely suggesting a library that can give you advanced JSON serializing and parsing, if you so happened to need it.

Comment: With Json.net you also get linq capabilities.  Very handy.